# Convert float to generic fixed point represented as an int

Tags: c++, python, math, hardware

I'm writing a software driver for some hardware I've built that implements fixed point only arithmetic. I've searched high and low but can't seem to find a generic algorithm that allows me to convert a float to fixed(x:y) +1 sign bit. I also want to represent this as an int so that I can test accuracy and speed comparison for general simulated algorithms written in both python and c++. (I'm using a 64bit Macbook Pro)

The closest to what I need I found on the Nokia site 
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Fixed-point_math_for_Python

But they only convert to 16:16 and did not quite understand where the constant 65536.0 comes from, whilst I required x:y.

EDIT ---
I am still finding that on the conversion back all fractional parts are lost, it is converting fixed2int not fixed2float

```
def float2fixed(a,y):
    return int(round(a*pow(2,y))) #added round for better accuracy

def fix2float(a,y):
    return float(a/pow(2,y))

a = 2.3
b = float2fixed(a,32)
print(b)
print(fix2float(b,32))
```

Output

```
9878424780
2.0
```

EDIT--Solution for when x = y in fixed(x:y). Will post method later for masking onto fixed(x:y) when x != y.

```
def float2fixed(a,y):
    return int(round(a*pow(2,y)))  #added round for better accuracy

def fix2float(a,y):
    return float(a/pow(2,y))
```

EDIT-- This new method gives a fixed Binary representation for any x(integer bits +1 sign) y(frac bits) signed not two's complement

```
def float2fixedBinary(a,x,y):
    #Set up fractional part in fixed point
    f = float2fixed(a,y)
    s = x+y
    binStr = '{0:0{width}b}'.format(f,width=s)
    #If -ve the - symbol is kept at the start of the string replace this
    return binStr.replace('-', '1')
```

Comment: `65536` is `pow(2, 16);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed point math uses the top X bits of an integer as the whole number part of a floating point number and the bottom Y bits as the fractional part. So, 123.456 would be something like 00001234560000 (I'm cheating because we'd really want the hex representation). The way you shift the float Y bits so that it fits in an integeger is to multiply by float(2**Y). In 16:16, 2**16 is 65536. If you are doing, say, 32:32, you'd shift float(2**32) or 4294967296.

Comment: Thank you, how would this work if x and y are different, so for example case x = 6 and y = 9 +1 sign bit?

Comment: My hardware only uses 16bit for now, would it work then if I shifted the float to a 32:32 and then spliced out the bit pattern I need to match the 16bit representation the hardware is using for the communication driver?

Comment: @SamPalmer - Generically, you use float(2**Y) for float2fixed and 1./float(2**y) for fixed2float. The example didn't use a sign bit which you would have to mask off separately.

Comment: I just tried to implement this in Python and found that I was losing all decimals on the conversion back, so it was just like converting back to an int not a float                                          def float2fixed(a,y):
    return int(a*pow(2,y))

def fix2float(a,y):
    return float(a/pow(2,y))

a = 2.3
b = float2fixed(a,23)
print(b)
print(fix2float(b,23))

Comment: @SamPalmer you need to convert to float earlier `float(a)/float(pow(2,y))`. Python will cast a automatically when the denominator is float so and since you use 2**y a lot, you might as well make it a variable. Something like `f_conv = float(pow(2,y))` as a global and `a/f_conv` later would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer only understands numbers as binary numbers, so when you do "fixed point" math, the point is placed in the integer at some fraction of two. More accurately, float just does all the math in counts of the smallest value representable in the fixed point.

In this example, they (rather arbitrarily, i might add) place the fixed point at bit 16 of a 32 bit integer. The smallest fraction represented by this number is 1/2^16 or (1/65536)

Comment: "64 bit image"? It's explicitly stated to be 32-bit (which probably means their Python is out of date), and I don't know what you mean by the "image" part.

Comment: @user2357112 It was a typo, sorry.